# Is a Kerberos ticket valid with only one-way external trust between domains?

Tags: authentication, iis, active-directory, kerberos, crossdomain

The situation is that I have two domains (Domain A and Domain B) that live on separate networks. I need to allow users in B to be authenticated with integrated windows authentication (IWA) when they hit a web app deployed on an IIS server in A. Currently, IIS returns a 401 when users in B try to hit the URL.

Possible Solution: Establish a trust between A and B so that users in B can be authenticated against A. B, however, is highly secured and will only allow A to establish one-way outgoing trust (A trusts B). So the question here is:

*Is the user's TGT from B valid on my IIS server in A, or will the IIS server still have to reach out to the the ActiveDirectory/domain controller in B (requiring two-way trust, presumably)?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from what i gather the IIS server is part of domain A, if so you can add a one way [trust between A->B](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731404(v=ws.11).aspx), this will cause all global/universal users in domain B to be trusted by domain A, allowing you to give access (on the IIS server) to domain B users.

for SSO/IWA you need that the IIS server be considered as part of the [intranet zone](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2012/06/05/the-intranet-zone/) by hosts in B, this will require either to have the same DNS suffix as domain A on hosts in domain B, on the same subnet or a manual addition to the intranet zone for that specific site.

a few points that i must clarify for you that will make this answer make more sense and give some insights into security boundaries in AD:

- The TGT is not sent to the IIS server, only a TGS.
- unless you have [PAC validation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/openspecification/2009/04/24/understanding-microsoft-kerberos-pac-validation/) enabled the IIS server will never contact the DC as part of the authentication sequence.
- [a trust is not a good security boundary](http://www.harmj0y.net/blog/redteaming/the-trustpocalypse/) (there are other mechanisms to limit access between domains, such as network segmentation and firewalling)
- [this is a great explanation about how kerberos works](http://www.roguelynn.com/words/explain-like-im-5-kerberos/)